# combine multiple count/group queries into one statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've been playing around with a method to return counts for users in multiple tables.

```
<?php

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `computer_username`, `computer_name`, COUNT(`computer_name`) `totalsum` FROM `table1`
        WHERE `account_id` = ? AND (`computer_name` = 'comp1' OR `computer_name` = 'comp2' OR `computer_name` = 'comp3')
        GROUP BY `computer_username`, `computer_name`
    ");

    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id']));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    //print out the array
    echo 'table1<br /><pre>',print_r($results,true),'</pre><br /><br />';

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `computer_username`, `computer_name`, COUNT(`computer_name`) `totalsum` FROM `table2`
        WHERE `account_id` = ? AND (`computer_name` = 'comp1' OR `computer_name` = 'comp2' OR `computer_name` = 'comp3')
        GROUP BY `computer_username`, `computer_name`
    ");

    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id']));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    //print out the array
    echo 'table2<br /><pre>',print_r($results,true),'</pre><br /><br />';

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `computer_username`, `computer_name`, COUNT(`computer_name`) `totalsum` FROM `table3`
        WHERE `account_id` = ? AND (`computer_name` = 'comp1' OR `computer_name` = 'comp2' OR `computer_name` = 'comp3')
        GROUP BY `computer_username`, `computer_name`
    ");

    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id']));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    //print out the array
    echo 'table3<br /><pre>',print_r($results,true),'</pre><br /><br />';

?>
```

This results in something similar to the following for each array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => Bob
            [computer_name] => comp1
            [totalsum] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => Steve
            [computer_name] => comp1
            [totalsum] => 27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => Sue
            [computer_name] => comp2
            [totalsum] => 7
        )

)
```

I am just trying to return each groups total row count in the database for each table.  Since the conditions are exactly the same and only the table names are different is there a way to return this all in one call?  I have been playing around with it all day, but using a query for each has been the only way I can get results so far.

Ideally I am looking for a one array result with something like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => Bob
            [computer_name] => comp1
            [table1] => 15
            [table2] => 34
            [table3] => 131
        )

        ... and so on for each computer_name/computer_username group

)
```

**EDIT :**

I made some progress with this...

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT computer_name, username, COUNT(computer_name) usercount
FROM users
WHERE `account_id` = ?
GROUP BY `username`, `computer_name`) a

JOIN 

(SELECT computer_name, computer_username, COUNT(computer_name) t1count
FROM t1
WHERE `account_id` = ?
GROUP BY `computer_username`, `computer_name`) b

JOIN

(SELECT computer_name, computer_username, COUNT(computer_name) t2count
FROM t2
WHERE `account_id` = ?
GROUP BY `computer_username`, `computer_name`) c

JOIN

(SELECT computer_name, computer_username, COUNT(computer_name) t3count
FROM t3
WHERE `account_id` = ?
GROUP BY `computer_username`, `computer_name`) d

ON a.username = b.computer_username AND a.username = c.computer_username AND a.username = d.computer_username
```

I start with `users` table as this will always have all username/computer group combinations listed.  The problem is for any results to be returned in the array the username/computer group must have entries in every other table as well (t1,t2,t3).

So say, Bob on computer1 has 5 rows in t1, 10 in t2, and 50 in t3 I will get those counts back in my array as t1count, t2count, t3count.  Sue on computer4 has 5 in t1, 0 and t2, and 12 in t3... because there were no rows in t2 none of her results are returned.

Is there any way around this or do joins explicitly require a matching value from one table to the next?

**EXAMPLE DATA AND expected result :**

```
//always contains every unique username/computer_name combination
`users` (username, computer_name)

bob, computer1
bob, computer8
steve, computer1
joe, computer3
sal, computer4
cindy, computer4
bill, computer8
jack, computer2

//contains data by computer_username/computer_name combo (can repeat)
`table1` (computer_username, computer_name)

bob, computer1
bob, computer8
bob, computer8
bob, computer8
steve, computer1
joe, computer3
joe, computer3
joe, computer3
bill, computer8
sal, computer4
sal, computer4
sal, computer4
cindy, computer4
bill, computer8

//contains data by computer_username/computer_name combo (can repeat)
`table2` (computer_username, computer_name)

bob, computer1
bob, computer1
bob, computer1
bob, computer8
bob, computer8
joe, computer3
joe, computer3
bill, computer8
sal, computer4
sal, computer4
cindy, computer4
cindy, computer4
cindy, computer4

//contains data by computer_username/computer_name combo (can repeat)
`table3` (computer_username, computer_name)

bob, computer8
steve, computer1
steve, computer1
steve, computer1
bill, computer8
bill, computer8
steve, computer1
sal, computer4
cindy, computer4
cindy, computer4

// resulting array on account_id = 1 and computer_name = (computer1, computer2, computer3, or computer4)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => bob
            [computer_name] => computer1
            [t1count] => 1
            [t2count] => 3
            [t3count] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => steve
            [computer_name] => computer1
            [t1count] => 1
            [t2count] => 0
            [t3count] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => joe
            [computer_name] => computer3
            [t1count] => 3
            [t2count] => 2
            [t3count] => 0
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => sal
            [computer_name] => computer4
            [t1count] => 3
            [t2count] => 2
            [t3count] => 1
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => cindy
            [computer_name] => computer4
            [t1count] => 1
            [t2count] => 3
            [t3count] => 2
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [computer_username] => jack
            [computer_name] => computer2
            [t1count] => 0
            [t2count] => 0
            [t3count] => 0
        )
)
```

Assume, all the tables above have a column called account_id = 1.  You have an account_id which represents the 'owner' of a computer.  Users is a table of all computers and all usernames on those computers.  table1, table2, table3 are records tied to the specific computer and specific user of that computer.  There can be zero or any amount of records for any specific user/computer pair in any of those tables.

The goal is to return counts for the records tables (table1, table2, table3) for each user given an account_id and list of computer_name's. No ordering of any kind is needed on the result.

Comment: couldn't you just join the tables? in one select

Comment: See UNION. Also, consider this: "AND computer_name IN ('comp1','comp2','comp3')". For further help, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the data provided and no ID's provided to query off of this will do what you want. 
see working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fb38/26)

```
SELECT 
  usr, 
  cmptr, 
  t1_count, 
  t2_count, 
  t3_count 
FROM (
  SELECT
    users.username AS usr,
    users.computer_name AS cmptr,
    count(t1.computer_name) AS t1_count
  FROM users
  JOIN t1 ON t1.computer_username = users.username AND t1.computer_name = users.computer_name
  GROUP BY users.username, users.computer_name
)AS t
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT
    users.username,
    users.computer_name,
    count(t2.computer_name) AS t2_count
  FROM users
  JOIN t2 ON t2.computer_username = users.username AND t2.computer_name = users.computer_name
  GROUP BY users.username, users.computer_name
) AS te ON te.username = t.usr OR te.computer_name = t.cmptr
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT
    users.username,
    users.computer_name,
    count(t3.computer_name) AS t3_count
  FROM users
  JOIN t3 ON t3.computer_username = users.username AND t3.computer_name = users.computer_name
  GROUP BY users.username, users.computer_name
) AS tem ON tem.username = t.usr OR tem.computer_name = t.cmptr
GROUP BY usr, cmptr
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it is throwing an ''SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064'...  I tried to explain it as best as I could.  Imagine the array result I posted as being the results for the first table.  There would be two more like that with the same computer_username/computer_name combo. Trying to get the group counts for each table in one array of results.

Comment: @user756659 why did you omit the only meaningful part of the error message?

Comment: if you could provide more details on the error message, like what the syntax is we can help more. if you could provide some raw data (like a few rows from each table) I can build a sql fiddle and get it working.

Comment: I added some data... hopefully that makes sense.  I could just do separate queries for this in a loop, but now I just want to see if it is possible more than anything.  Plus this is helping me learn more as I go... I obviously need to step up my knowledge with queries like this.

Comment: Ok cool, i'll look at it in a minute. should be possible. however generally I think its best to have id's for each user and make a foreign key as user_id in the other tables to more normalize it.

Comment: Every table has a unique primary key... for instance every user in 'users' table has a unique user_id column.  I am somewhat limited with what I can do db-wise due to other coding in place.

Comment: does that unique user_id get set in the other tables as a foreign key?

Comment: i just updated my answer with a working copy to do what you want. if you can provide the id's for the users with the id's in the other tables as foreign keys this query will be much smaller and take less computing time.

Comment: I just took a look and the db is using MyISAM.  I did some quick searching and I can only use foreign keys with innodb.  All of this is somewhat new to me, but from what I have read it looks like this should certainly be using innodb.

Comment: WOW - thank you!  I can't specify account_id and computer_name with this though.  I need a clause to only return values where account_id = 1 and computer_name = (computer1, computer2, computer3, or computer4).  In the case of the example data I provided all tables have an account_id column = 1, but I only want to show computer1, computer2, computer3, or computer4... so bill and bob on computer8 should not show.  Or I guess I could filter those out from the array afterwards.

Comment: Looks like some of the results are off as well.  This gives me a good start to work with though!

Comment: you can just add those to the first select part... inside the FROM(... ) as t... the rest are joined off of there so it should filter them out :)